# HLOOKUP with wildcard and SUM more than one column

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I need help with the following:

1. I have a worksheet containing some data. Row 1 is header and from row 2 downward is the data. At the end there is total for all the data above. This worksheet is dynamic, i.e., if week 1 has 200 rows of data, then week 2 could have 250 or 190 rows of data.

Likewise, the columns across, change every week. This week I have 18 columns and next week I could have 20 columns.

1. Within row # 1, the header, I have two headings "CTAEO1P" and "CTAEO2P".
2. On another worksheet, I want to add the "totals" of both of those columns i.e., Individual totals of CTAEO1P = 32.98 + CTAEO2P = 46.25 = 79.23
3. I am using named ranges and named the whole of the worksheet with data as "MT". The range is whole of the worksheet so when next week I copy the data over from another worksheet, I should not have to adjust the range.
4. I am using the following formula, courtesy of another expert on this forum:

=HLOOKUP("CT*",MT,MATCH(9^99,INDEX(MT,0,MATCH("CT*",INDEX(MT,1,0),0))),0)

1. This formula look for any column that starts with "CT" and then "Match(9^99" and "index" finds the last number within that column (the total in this case) and then return that value on the worksheet. In this case this formula is returning "32.98" only, as this is the first occurrence.
2. I think I can use "Sumproduct" formula here but then a) I would have to create more than one named range, one for the header row and another for the "Total" row, b) every week I would have to adjust the range for "Total" row. Unless, if I can nest "Match(9^99..." part within "SUMPRODUCT" function.
3. I want to use "MT" range alone and want to add the totals of all the columns that start with "CT".

I hope I have been able to explain my problem better enough to make some sense, however, if you need any further information, then please let me know.

Regards

Tariq

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING? *(I've removed the shouting for you on this occasion.)*

Comment: I posted an answer but I also note that you can make the formula in 4. above simpler by using this version - `=LOOKUP(9^99,INDEX(MT,0,MATCH("CT*",INDEX(MT,1,0),0)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will forget about the MT range, as long as your data starts in A1 this will work

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CT*";OFFSET(A1;0;0;1;MATCH(9^99;2:2))))*OFFSET(A1;MATCH(9^99;A:A)-1;0;1;MATCH(9^99;2:2)))
```

Depending on your regional settings you may need to replace field separator ";" by ","

Comment: It may not be an issue here but if you SEARCH for "CT*" that will match with any column that **contains** "CT" in the header rather than just those starting with "CT" - I would use LEFT function as per my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a relatively simple `SUMPRODUCT` solution like this

`=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(INDEX(MT,1,0),2)="CT")*ISNUMBER(MT),MT)/2`

SUMPRODUCT will total **all** values in the relevant columns, including the totals so divison by 2 will ensure you get the correct count

If you don't like that approach then assuming first column of MT always has data and that the totals for each column will all be in the same row you can use `SUMIF` like this

`=SUMIF(INDEX(MT,1,0),"CT*",INDEX(MT,MATCH(9^99,INDEX(MT,0,1)),0))`

That should be more efficient than the first version

Comment: Thank you very much Barry. Although all the formulas worked but "SUMIF" worked better. The sub-totals for each column started after column 27, so I changed the last bit of the formula as "....,INDEX(MT,0,27)),0))". Thank you very much.